# Not quite sure where the log-likelihood function comes from

Tags: self-study, generalized-linear-model, likelihood

> A Poisson variable $Y_i$ is believed to depend on a covariate $x_i$ and it is propsed that log-linear model with a systematic component $a + bx_i$ is appropriate. In an experiment the following values were observed:
>
> *values not important to question*
>
> Write down the log-likelihood function for the proposed log-linear model for these data.

So I did this, the normal linear model would just be that $\lambda = a + bx_i$ and this would go into the PDF for a Poisson distribution and would give you:

$$f(y: a + bx_i) = \exp \{y \ln(a + bx_i) - (a + bx_i) - \ln(y!)\}$$

So the log-linear model would just be the log of this function giving us

$$y \ln(a + bx_i) - (a + bx_i) - \ln(y!)$$

And so to find the log-likelihood function would be

$$\sum_{i =1}^n y_i \ln(a + bx_i) - (a + bx_i) - \ln(y_i!)$$

But the answers say it should be

$$\sum_{i =1}^n y_i (a + bx_i) - \exp(a + bx_i) - \ln(y_i!)$$

How do they get this?

Comment: You did everything right--but you started out wrong, at least if you're doing [Poisson regression with a log link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression). There the *log* expectation is assumed to be a linear function of $x$: $\log(\lambda) = a + b x_i$ should then be your point of departure.

Comment: @whuber So why do we have $\exp(..)$ in the log-likelihood function? Is it because I want it to be just $\lambda$ but obviously its in terms of $\ln(\lambda)$ and so I just $\exp$ it to get it to be just $\lambda$? Is this the starting point for all log linear models, given the systematic component?

Comment: You don't have exp() in the log-likelihood. You have exp() in the likelihood. Taking logs gets rid of that, then taking the derivative wrt to the parameter leads to the maximum. Remember that the likelihood from an independent sample is a product of density (or probability) functions. Taking logs gives you a sum, and in the case of the Poisson, simplifies the functional form as well. That's why we like the exponential family of distributions. Good luck with your homework.

Comment: The exponential in the (correct) log-likelihood function is $\lambda$ itself, because $\lambda = \exp(a + b x_i)$. Indeed, that's a good way to go about writing the function: write the log-likelihood first in terms of $\lambda$ (it equals $y\log(\lambda) - \lambda - \log(y!)$) and then simply substitute $\exp(a + b x_i)$ (or, more generally, whatever the inverse link function is) for $\lambda$ and simplify if you like.